Operations on recyclerview rows
I have a recycler view with 10 rows. Each row has some edittexts and one textview. My objective is to sum the values of each textview from these 10 recycler view rows and display the result in additional textview outside which is not a part of this recycler view. How do we achieve this please advise
I tried many wYs like extracting String but failed altogether
